# If I were to take a video of a man fully clothed, not an inch of skin showing, would this be okay, since it’s just my clothes not a living being?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith-interpretation

I imagine it as taking a picture of a tree, but there is a man behind it, not visible. Would this be halal as the clothing is the only thing visible which has no soul? Even the eyes would be covered.